# Can Inner tube 1.25 / 1.5 fit 26x1.4 tire?

Tags: tire, innertube

I have a tire 26 X 1.4 what size tube should I buy for it? 1.25 or 1.5 Inner tube ?

Comment: If I buy 26 x 1.5 to 1.75 event thought my tire is 1.4 can I still use it ? Or is it too big for my tire and will not fit perfectly ? I saw my nearest bike store sell it , can't wait to ride . Thanks btw

Comment: Inner tubes come with a range of widths stamped on the box.  Pick one whose range contains 1.4".  And if you can't find the exact diameter I'd favor picking the next narrower tube vs the next wider one, if the difference is about the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most 26x1.25 sized tubes are rated from 1.25" up to 1.5". You should be fine with the 26x1.25 tube as long as that's the lowest size indication on the tube.

Though most tubes you'll find will indicate an acceptable low/high range. You're likely to find the tubes indicated as 26x1.25/1.5 which should fit any sizes listed or between.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you can buy 1.5 - 1.75 now but they don't have 1.25 - 1.5 in stock?

If so yes 1.4 is very close to 1.5.  As with any install be careful not to pinch the tube when installing the tire.  Fill it up to 10 psi and release pressure to relieve folds / twist.